# Using Flow to update a lookup field based on a picklist value

Tags: visual-workflow

I have two custom fields on the Opportunity object, one is picklist field and the other is lookup field that's related to a custom object. The lookup field is a new field that has been added after the fact.
If the picklist is a certain value: "A", "B", "C" or "D", I want the lookup field to return the corresponding record of the custom object using the recordID.

So if picklist = "A", then lookup field will return the custom object record "A", and so on.

Is this possible using Flow Builder? I'm new to this so if you need further clarification, or I've gotten it completely wrong, you won't hurt my feelings.

And can this be done on Opportunity records that already exist with the picklist values already selected?

Comment: Do you have matching records on the custom object as per the picklist values on the opportunity records? If yes, then you can use lookup filters on opportunity. Refer the https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_lookup_filters_examples.htm&type=5

Comment: I do. I'm trying to accomplish this to make it easier on the client since they've already created the picklist on the opportunity and instead of revamping the way they do things, just trying to make it easier so they don't have one more field to fill out that will say the exact same thing as their picklist choice.